# Prove if $a$ and $n$ are not relatively prime, there exists an integer $b$ with $1\leq b<n$ such that $ab\equiv0\pmod n$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $n\in{\mathbb{Z}},n>1$, and let $a\in{\mathbb{Z}}$ with $1\leq a\leq n$ prove if $a$ and $n$ are not relatively prime, there exists an integer $b$ with $1\leq b<n$ such that $ab\equiv0\pmod n$ and deduce that there cannot be an integer $c$ such tthat $ac\equiv1\pmod n$.

My attempt: If $a$ and $n$ are not relatively prime then $g.c.d>1$. Let $b=g.c.d$ then there exist $x,y\in{\mathbb{Z}}$ such that

$ax+ny=(a,n)=b$

And because $b=g.c.d$, $b|a$ and $b|n$ so $ 1\leq b\leq \min(a,n)$. Then we can write

$\frac{ab}{n}=\frac{a(ax+ny)}{n}=\frac{a^2x}{n}+ay$

Now I don't know how to prove that $n|(a^2x)$ and $b$ isn't necessarily $<n$. Can someone help me?

Comment: Hint : There must be some prime $p$ dividing both $a$ and $n$. Now consider $b:=\frac{n}{p}$

Comment: Another hint : An element in a ring cannot be both a unit and a zero-divisor.

Comment: For the conclusion, if $a$ is a zero divisor in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, then it cannot be a unit in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. Furthermore, if $a=4$ and $6=n$, then $2=1\cdot 6 - 1 \cdot 4$ gives $x=-1, y=1$ and $gcd(a,n)=2$. Note here that it is not the case that $n \text{ }|\text{ }a^2 x$, as $6 \text{ }\not|\text{ } 16$.

Comment: $c$ can exist, like $n=2$, $c=a=1$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $b=\dfrac n{\gcd(a,n)}$. Since
$$ab=a\cdot\dfrac n{\gcd(a,n)}=n\cdot\dfrac a{\gcd(a,n)},$$
where $\dfrac a{\gcd(a,n)}$ is an integer, $ab\equiv0\pmod n$. Also $\gcd(a,n)\ge2$, so $1\le b<n$.

Towards a contradiction, suppose there is an integer $c$ such that $ac\equiv1\pmod n$.
Multiplying by $b$, we obtain $acb\equiv b\pmod n$.
On the other hand, $acb\equiv0\pmod n$ since $ab\equiv0\pmod n$.
So, $b\equiv0\pmod n$, which is absurd since $1\le b<n$.
Hence it cannot be true that there is an integer $c$ such that $ac\equiv1\pmod n$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative proof that uses counting:

**Proof:**
Consider the below set
$$
S = \{ax \ : \ 1 \leq x < n \}
$$

We are done if we can show that
$$
ax_1 \equiv ax_2 \pmod{n} \quad 1\leq x_2 < x_1 <n \qquad \qquad (\ast)
$$
as this would imply that $a(x_1 - x_2) \equiv 0 \pmod{n}$.

There are n-1 values of $x$. Observe that
\begin{align*}
ax \equiv 1 \pmod{n} &\implies ax - 1 = nq \ \text{for some $q \in \mathbb{Z}$} \\
&\implies ax - nq = 1 \\
&\implies \gcd(a,n) = 1 \ \tag{by Bézout},
\end{align*}
a contradiction. Thus, if $ax \not\equiv 0$ for all $1 \leq x < n$ then
since $ax \not\equiv 1$, we have that $ax$ can take at most $n-2$ values modulo $n$. By Pigeonhole we get $(\ast)$ completing the proof.